# Android Stripe createSource method never returns

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am calling createSource method of Stripe in Android, it works about 70% of the time and other time it simply doesn't call `onSuccess` nor `onError`.
Here is my code:

```
            SourceParams cardSourceParams = SourceParams.createCardParams(card);
            mStripe.createSource(
                    cardSourceParams,
                    new SourceCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Source source) {
                            if (source != null) {
                             // I do my work
                             }else {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "source is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Exception error) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: There have been a few instances of this, but it seems like if you create a callback without using an inline anonymous function, the problem will generally disappear.  Stripe is already working on figuring out why this is happening.

Comment: This is where it was originally reported, but it has come up a few times now--  https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues/803#issuecomment-461840143